# Can you use the verb "parler" informally for the meaning "réussir / convenir"?

Tags: sens

> Choisissez la méthode qui vous **parle** le plus et essayez de la mettre en pratique le plus régulièrement possible afin que des taches trop coriaces ne se forment pas.

I wonder how it  differs in meaning from saying:

> Choisissez la méthode qui vous **réussit / convient** le mieux.

Comment: À comparer avec « Ça te **parle** de prendre un verre ? »

Comment: @LukeSawczak Hi. This is the first time I've heard this turn of phrase. Do you mean "Ça te **dirait / dit** de prendre un verre ?", or does "parle" work just as well?

Comment: Whoops, that's clearly what I had in mind with the second half of that sentence! Merci. I should have said something more like « Ça te parle, le changement climatique ? » Does that mean anything to you; have you heard of it?

Comment: @LukeSawczak The funny thing is that even with the meaning of "Does that mean anything to you", I would still use "dire" like "Ça te **dit** quelque chose ?". I've never heard of "Ça te **parle** quelque chose ?" from French speakers around me, at least. So « Ça te parle, + noun » might well be a less common version, I suppose?

Comment: It's not informal at all, I shouldn't think. It's not: Ça te parle quelque chose. It's just: Ça me parle, Ça te parle? No quelque chose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Parler* is similar to *speak to* (in the sense of *appeal to*) in that case.

> to be interesting or attractive :  APPEAL
>
> - great music … speaks directly to the emotions — A. N. Whitehead

[(Merriam Webster - speak 3.c)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speak)

In contrast,

> Choisissez la méthode qui vous **réussit** le mieux

implies that you've tested the method before and have had some success with it. *Parler* implies the opposite. *Ce qui vous parle* is what appeals to you at first sight, on a first impression as opposed to a tested and proven option.

> Choisissez la méthode qui vous **convient** le mieux

(*that suits you best*) could be interpreted both ways but is more likely to express effective suitability than a simple feeling.

Answer (score 5):

*Parler* is colloquial for *inspirer* here:

> *Choisissez la méthode qui vous **inspire** le plus…*

Answer (score 0):

When you use *parler* it's like a metaphor, because you don't mean to speak really. It's to ask unformally an opinion.